# Show selected ListBoxItem's value on a label

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a sort of Windows Form "game" you could say about evolving humans. I created a code to generate a random tribe member when the Add button is pushed:

```
    public void addpop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        RandomName = rand.Next(Database.tribalage_Names.Length); //creates random name for pop.
        RandomSex = rand.Next(Database.sex.Length); //chooses a random sex for pop.
        RandomStartingAge = rand.Next(16, 34); //selects a random age for pop.
        RandomLevel = rand.Next(0, 5); //generates a random skill level for pop.


        if (Settings.TribePopulation <= 6) //creates the randomly generated human.
        {
            Human startinghuman = new Human(1, Database.tribalage_Names[RandomName], Database.sex[RandomSex], RandomStartingAge, RandomLevel, RandomLevel, RandomLevel, RandomLevel, RandomLevel, 100, "healthy", "curious of surroundings", "desire to create a shelter", "normal", "neutral");
            lb_poplist.Items.Add(startinghuman.Name); //adds the created human to a list.
        }
```

Now what I want to do is when I click the "View" button, I'm able to read all of the values from that created human and project them onto labels.

```
 public void viewpop_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tb_popname.Text = lb_poplist.SelectedItem.ToString(); //This works in showing the human's name.
        lbl_humanage.Text = lb_poplist.SelectedItem??????? //THIS is what im stumped on. Getting the age of the created human, and turning that int into the value of this label.

    }
```

I pretty much want to be able to randomly generate these Human objects and be able to view all the ints and strings of the specific one I generated in the list. I'm stumped!

Comment: Depending on how you have things set up, this may work: `(lb_poplist.SelectedItem as Human).WhateverPropertyYouNeed;`

Comment: Actually my above comment will only work if you change `lb_poplist.Items.Add(startinghuman.Name)` to `lb_poplist.Items.Add(startinghuman)` and set `myListBox.DisplayMember = "Name"`

Comment: @CodingYoshi This worked!! You are the best! Thank you! This is going to save me SO much trouble.

Comment: You should also have `Random rand = new Random();` at FORM level, not inside the event handler.